# Upgrading headlamps

Tags: hyundai, headlight, i20

Due to low visibility of the road from stock headlamps I want to replace stock halogen headlamp assembly with projector headlamp assembly which comes with the top end variant. The price quoted by the showroom is quite high. When I searched for genuine parts I will get pair of projector headlamps for lesser price!

My question is, if I install the genuine projector headlamps does it require re-wiring or any sort of modification to the existing electric supply? If so will that void the warranty of the car?

Initially I thought about other options like installing higher luminous halogen or led lights. The problem with this is higher watt halogen requires additional wiring and for led lights the weather seal cap has to be removed due to this dust and water will get into the headlight which will damage the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If the bulbs are different and I assume HID from what you wrote, then yes there are differences.

You will need the HID driver units and possibly associated wiring - which may also need changes or upgrades in the fuse box. There is also usually wiring and control for anti-dazzling to be fitted - if you don’t then it can fail subsequent inspections...

Could explain why the dealer price was higher...

Comment: What if the project setup is of LED bulb instead of HID? does it still require additional wiring and fuse modification?

Comment: Led drivers are not hid drivers imho